# How do I enrich a case class with minimal changes to the codebase?

Tags: scala, generics, case-class, companion-object, enrich-my-library

Using scala 2.11.12.

Scattered all over my code base I have a case class like this:

```
case class Landscape(
  north: Sight,
  east: Sight,
  south: Sight,
  west: Sight
) {
  def toList: List[Sight] = List(north, east, south, west)

  def isIdyllic: Boolean = north.isPastoral && east.isPastoral && south.isPastoral && west.isPastoral
}
```

(with a custom case class `Sight`) and a corresponding companion object:

```
object Landscape {
  def fromSeq(s: Seq[Sight]): Landscape = {
    require(s.length == 4)

    Landscape(
      north = s(0),
      east = s(1),
      south = s(2),
      west = s(3)
    )
  }

  def pickByBeautifulSouth(scape1: Landscape, scape2: Landscape): Landscape = {
    if (scape1.south.beauty > scape2.south.beauty) scape1 else scape2
  }
}
```

It turned out that it would be useful to have similar types, so I created a generic case class:

```
case class Compass[A](
  north: A,
  east: A,
  south: A,
  west: A
) {
  def toList: List[A] = List(north, east, south, west)
}
```

with a corresponding companion object:

```
object Compass {
  def fromSeq[A](s: Seq[A]): Compass[A] = {
    require(s.length == 4)

    Compass[A](
      north = s(0),
      east = s(1),
      south = s(2),
      west = s(3)
    )
  }
}
```

Obviously `isIdyllic` and `pickByBeautifulSouth` don't make sense for arbitrary types `A`.
Now I'd like to make `Landscape` an enriched `Compass`, so I don't have to define `toList` and `fromSeq` in `Landscape` anymore.

I know I cannot do

```
case class Landscape(
  north: Sight,
  east: Sight,
  south: Sight,
  west: Sight
) extends Compass[Sight] {
  def isIdyllic: Boolean = north.isPastoral && east.isPastoral && south.isPastoral && west.isPastoral
}
```

since case-to-case inheritance is not possible. I also cannot make Compass[A] a trait like this:

```
trait Compass[A]{
  def north: A
  def east: A
  def south: A
  def west: A

  def toList: List[A] = List(north, east, south, west)
}
```

because that way I would break `fromSeq` which makes use of `Compass`'s fields and its apply method.

I also thought of using an implicit class

```
implicit class LandscapeOps(ls: Compass[Sight]) {
  def isIdyllic: Boolean = ls.north.isPastoral && ls.east.isPastoral && ls.south.isPastoral && ls.west.isPastoral
}
```

and type-aliasing in my codebase

```
type Landscape = Compass[Sight]
```

however, this way I would again break my code by losing `Landscape`'s apply method. And I also don't know how to add `pickByBeautifulSouth`.

Long story short: I'm looking for a way to

- make `Landscape` use `Compass`, so I don't have to duplicate `toList` and `fromSeq`
- achieve this with minimal changes in the codebase, i.e. `Landscape(sight1, sight2, sight3, sight4)` and `Landscape.copy(west=someSight)` should still work, as well as `Landscape.pickByBeautifulSouth(scape1, scape2)`

Comment: `fromSeq` is not reusable since you can't abstract over constructors anyways. - BTW, in the `type alias` approach you can also alias the companion object like this `val Landscape = Compass` which is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood all the limitations but ..
Why not a trait `Compass[T]` and a subtype `Landscape`

```scala
trait Compass[A] {
  val north: A
  val east: A
  val south: A
  val west: A
  def toList: List[A] = List(north, east, south, west)
}

case class Landscape(
  north: Sight,
  east: Sight,
  south: Sight,
  west: Sight
) extends Compass[Sight] {
  def isIdyllic: Boolean = north.isPastoral && east.isPastoral && south.isPastoral && west.isPastoral
}
```

then the whole Landscape object still works

```
object Landscape {
  def fromSeq(s: Seq[Sight]): Landscape = {
    require(s.length == 4)

    Landscape(
      north = s(0),
      east = s(1),
      south = s(2),
      west = s(3)
    )
  }

  def pickByBeautifulSouth(scape1: Landscape, scape2: Landscape): Landscape =
    ???
}
```

Comment: I didn't want to use the trait approach, because I didn't want to duplicate fromSeq for other Compasses that I want to use.
If I e.g. make another case class, say, Distances(...) extends Compass[BigDecimal], I would have to implement fromSeq again for Distances.
But if I cannot reuse fromSeq anyway, as @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez pointed out, I might actually use the trait or the aliasing approach.

Answer (score 0):

So here's a minimal working example of what I ended up with:

```
case class Sight() {
  def isPastoral: Boolean = true
  def beauty: Int = 5
}

case class Compass[A](
  north: A,
  east: A,
  south: A,
  west: A
) {
  def toList: List[A] = List(north, east, south, west)
}

object Compass {
  def fromSeq[A](s: Seq[A]): Compass[A] = {
    require(s.length == 4)

    Compass[A](
      north = s(0),
      east = s(1),
      south = s(2),
      west = s(3)
    )
  }
}

object LandscapeModule {
  type Landscape = Compass[Sight]
  val Landscape = Compass

  implicit class LandscapeOps(ls: Landscape) {
    import ls._

    def isIdyllic: Boolean = north.isPastoral && east.isPastoral && south.isPastoral && west.isPastoral
  }
  
  object LandscapeOps {
    def pickByBeautifulSouth(scape1: Landscape, scape2: Landscape): Landscape = {
      if (scape1.south.beauty > scape2.south.beauty) scape1 else scape2
    }
  }
}

object HowToUseIt {
  import LandscapeModule.{Landscape, LandscapeOps}

  val sight = Sight()
  val sights: Seq[Sight] = Seq.fill(4)(sight)

  val landscape: Landscape = Landscape(north = sight, east = sight, south = sight, west = sight)
  val landscapeFromSeq = Landscape.fromSeq(sights)

  LandscapeOps.pickByBeautifulSouth(landscape, landscapeFromSeq)
}
```

This way I only had to change two things in my codebase:

- the imports: `import LandscapeModule.{Landscape, LandscapeOps}` instead of `import Landscape`
- calls to landscape's custom factory methods other than `fromSeq`: `LandscapeOps.pickByBeautifulSouth` instead of `Landscape.pickByBeautifulSouth`